# Are ALL images 72dpi in web browsers?

Tags: html, css, fancybox

I've used Fancybox (and similar) in the past to display images on websites.  When I upload images to the server that are higher resolution than 72dpi, they usually take noticeably longer for Fancybox to load and display.

I was under the impression that all websites were displayed at 72dpi, and I threw images in under that general assumption.  Can images be displayed at higher resolutions in a web browser?  Is that why these images that I've used take longer to load?  Or are they still displayed at 72dpi, but have to be scaled every time the page loads?

Thank you.

Comment: http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/02/the-myth-of-dpi/

Comment: Why all the downvotes?  At least add something to the question to improve it, or explain what may be wrong with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are shown at the resolution and dpi in which they are - for example; if i upload an 388dpi image to my site it will show at 388dpi at the same original resolution. The evidence behind this is that I am a web app developer. When first testing with one of my first apps we uploaded a full background image at 72dpi and the text wasnt very good so we made it higher dpi and same res and all worked perfectly!

Hope this helps!